# Actionscript 3.0 calling Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript, call, external

So, I'm using `ExternalInterface.call("functionNameInJavascript");` but it doesn't work...
In the HTML wrapper I set `allowScriptAccess` to `always` in both places:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Have you added `import flash.external.*` in your class?

Comment: Could you show the JavaScript function part from the HTML wrapper?

Comment: You need to provide more information so that we can better guess the issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I added import flash.external.*; (Actually imported flash.external.ExternalInterface but that doens't matter)

The JavaScript function is a basic one like this:
function functionNameInJavascript()
{
     alert("Hi");
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running the html page locally in your browser and not through a web server? (When you run it locally the browser address bar starts with "file:").

When the Flash Player runs in local security sandbox like that there's restrictions.

**There's two solutions:**

1. Test the page through a web server (you can setup a local server on your computer)
2. Configure the Flash Player to trust the file when running in local security sandbox.

I'm just going to describe the second step. Go to the [Global Security Settings Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) page. Even though it's a panel on a web page it's actually for configuring the settings in the Flash Player installed on your computer, which can be a bit confusing.

Click on *"Edit locations"* and then *"Add location"*. Enter the folder where you have your flash project(s), for instance "C:\projects\flash\".

**Making it work in Chrome:**

The Global Security Settings panel only affects the Flash Player plugin on your computer. If you're using Chrome this panel won't have any effect since Chrome uses its own built in version of the Flash Player by default. Therefore you need to tell Chrome not to use the built in version but the normal plugin instead:

1. Type in "chrome://plugins/" in the address bar in Chrome.
2. You should see two "Shockwave Flash" plugins. Inactivate the one which is of type "PPAPI" and make sure the one with type "NPAPI" is activated.
3. Done!